# Display table data after clicking on submit button Javascript HTML

Tags: javascript, html

My Requirement :

User enter's a product name in search box. I need to do show price for that product by calling java script function.

My HTML :

```
<form class="form-wrapper cf">
                            <input type="text" id="valbox" placeholder="Search here..." required>
                            <button type="submit" id="butval">Search</button>
                        </form>
```

My Java Script Function :

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="includes/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')
                window.onload = function(){
                document.getElementById('butval').onclick = function(){
                    var product= document.getElementById('valbox').value;   
                    initComparison('mobile_phones',product,'saibrpwx','HGYMDNVKJGSPFQCP');
                }
}; 
    </script>
    </script>
```

I am facing problem in displaying data since it's disappearing so fast.  Kindly let me know where is the error and how to fix it please.

Comment: Actually there's no error, the code works as it is. Why do you use `input type="submit"`, if you don't need the form to be submitted? Use `type="button"` instead.

Comment: Correct, add `return false;` at the end of click event function.

Comment: @Teemu Its a search box where user enters product name and click on search button.  Then table need to be displayed which is not working.  Would be great if you share your knowledge with me to fix this

Comment: @user2603466 Didn't I share the knowledge?

Comment: @skobaljic : Thanks for your input when i add return false as suggested. Data is getting displayed.  but if i enter another product name in search box without refreshing the page new data as well as old data both are displayed. How to fix that?

Comment: Modify your `initComparision` function to remove html content before providing new. I do not know what is your placeholder for search, can just guess.

Comment: @skobaljic initComparison function must accept only 4 parameters as stated above.  I dont understand how to remove html content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/jfs5j67h/

```
 <form class="form-wrapper cf" id="cf-form">
  <input type="text" id="valbox" placeholder="Search here..." required>
  <button type="submit" id="butval">Search</button>
</form>

$("#cf-form").on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var product=$('#valbox').val();
   // alert($('#valbox').val());
    initComparison('mobile_phones',product,'saibrpwx','HGYMDNVKJGSPFQCP');


});
```

1. First you want to prevent default behavior of form which is submit by preventDefault.
2. Use form submit event instead of click event if you want search to work when user press enter too.

Comment: @ Mayank Gupta valbox should be passed as input to initComparison function as stated above.  Can you please tell me where to call that function and how to do that

Comment: @ Mayank Gupta Thanks a lot for your kind assitance

Answer (score 0):

the form is submitting you could use the submit in the form like this

```
$("form").submit(function(){
     if(comparehere){
          return true; //send the form to the server

     }else{
         return false; //not send the form because is invalid
      }
})
```

sorry if this is not your answare , but you need to not submit the form until is validated with javascript you could also add onsubmit="return false;" on the form tag

Answer (score -1):

I have used DOM model to interact with the browser. After that I have assigned variables and arrays to store the each columns data . "AddRow" is a function which will add new row for us when we pressed the "Submit" button. Then used ".getElementById" method, it will returns the element that has the ID attribute with the specified value. Incrementing the variables for adding new row. Make sure to connect the given function "Addrow" ,to "Submit" button using style tag.

```
<script>
    let x=0;
    let n=1;
    var list1=[];
    var list2=[];
    var list3=[];
    var list4=[];
    //creating function
    function AddRow(){
        var AddRow = document.getElementById("show");
        var NewRow = AddRow.insertRow(n);

        list1[x] = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        list2[x] = document.getElementById("lname").value;
        list3[x] = document.getElementById("email").value;
        list4[x] = document.getElementById("age").value;

        var cel1=NewRow.insertCell(0);
        var cel2=NewRow.insertCell(1);
        var cel3=NewRow.insertCell(2);
        var cel4=NewRow.insertCell(3);

        cel1.innerHTML=list1[x];
        cel2.innerHTML=list2[x];
        cel3.innerHTML=list3[x];
        cel4.innerHTML=list4[x];

        x++;
        n++;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please dont just paste the code, explain the code as well.